# data.table := not working in a package function

Tags: r, data.table, r-package

I have a moved a function I created into an R package and it has stopped working. I get an error:

```
Error in `:=`((value), 1) : 
Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").
```

Weirdly this works if I load the function into the environment but not from the package? it seems very weird behaviour... I even check for whether it is a `data.table` in the function to stop this very thing!

```
data = as.data.table(mtcars)

# I Go into the package, highlight the function and run the code, to load the function into the environment  
# This works
create_dummy_var(data, var="cyl")

# This doesn't work (get the error message from above)
myPackage::create_dummy_var(data, var="cyl")
```

The original whole function

```
#' Converts a variable into a dummy variable
#'
#' Converts a single variable which contains a limited number of values into numeous dummary variables,
#' of 1 if the value is present 0 otherwise. The number of createds vars is equal to the number of unique observations in the varaiable
#'
#' @param dtable A data.table (must be data.table NOT data.frame or tibble)
#' @param var The variable to operate on
#'
#' @return data.table
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' 
#' df = data.frame("alp" = c("a", "a", "b", "d", "b"), "adults" = 1:5)
#' 
#' dt = data.table::data.table(df)
#' 
#' create_dummy_var(dt, "alp")
create_dummy_var <- function(dtable, var) {
  
  if (!var %in% names(dtable)) stop(var, " not found in dt")
  if(all(class(dtable) != "data.table")) stop("dt must be a data.table")
  
  dtable[, value := 1L]
  
  dcast(dtable , ...  ~ dtable[[var]] , value.var = "value", fill = 0, with = FALSE)
}
```

To replicate put this into an R package (you can use RStudio's new project, New Package template for the boiler plate).

```
> packageVersion("data.table")
[1] ‘1.14.2’
```

Comment: did you import `data.table` into the package? `#' @import data.table`

Comment: Did you read importing data.table vignette?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to jangorecki for pointing out the [Importing data.table vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-importing.html)

The issue was declaring `data.table`'s special symbols in the NAMESPACE.

The Importing data.table vignette does not mention that if you are using roxygen2 to  generate the NAMESPACE then you can't use `import(data.table)` in the NAMESPACE. But as always the excellent `usethis` package has it covered, with `usethis::use_data_table()`. This creates all the boilerplate and it now works :)

Comment: I have a similar issue: `no visible global function definition for :=`.  data.table is added in the DESCRIPTION file (but under Suggests, and not import). I also added `#' @import data.table` at the top of my R file. Could I ask where/how did you use use `this::use_data_table()`?

Comment: In the package root run `usethis::use_data_table()` . This will add a `R/datatabletest-package.R'` file - datatabletest being the name of my example package. It will also edit the DESCRIPTION and NAMESPACE files. 

- You need then `usethis` package installed